# Type of Vector's Elements for Use in Iterator Type

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, struct, types

If I have a struct `s`:

```
template<typename T>
struct s {
    std::vector<T> list;
};
```

Defined in `main()` as:

```
s<long double> x;
```

And I try to get the type of `list`'s iterator using:

```
typedef typename std::vector<decltype(x.list[0])>::iterator IT;
```

GCC 7.2.1 produces a bunch of errors, beginning with:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:392:27: error: forming pointer to reference type 'long double&'
    using pointer = _Tp*;
                        ^
```

I doubt there is anything wrong with the underlying implementation of C++ in GCC, which this error seems to indicate.

Using this method also assumes that `list` is not empty, so I instead tried using `::value_type` (as suggested on other SO answers):

```
typedef typename std::vector<x.list::value_type>::iterator IT;
```

GCC again produces errors:

```
error: the value of 'x' is not usable in a constant expression.
    typedef typename std::vector<x.list::value_type>::iterator IT;
                                   ^~~~
```

---

In order to find an alternative, I added a type-holding variable to the struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct s {
    T typeholder;
    std::vector<T> list;
};
```

And this worked fine, using:

```
typedef typename std::vector<decltype(x.typeholder)>::iterator IT;
```

Where am I going wrong here? It seems convoluted to need to define an unused variable just to hold the type. Am I misusing `::value_type`?

Comment: In your case: `using IT = decltype(x.list.begin());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `decltype(x.list[0])` is `long double&`. `std::vector` cannot store references, hence you get an error. The second error ("error: the value of 'x' is not usable in a constant expression.") also seems pretty obvious: you need a type instead of a value. This should compile without errors:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct s {
    std::vector<T> list;
};

int main()
{
    s<long double> x;
    typedef typename std::vector<decltype(x.list)::value_type>::iterator IT;
}
```

Comment: What's the reasoning behind having it be a reference type, instead of just a normal `long double`?